# Roblox Lua cannot access modulescript function

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to connect a ModuleScript to a server Script, and it's throwing the error: `Workspace.Script:6: attempt to call field 'check3' (a nil value)`

ModuleScript

```
local GunStats = {}
local part = workspace:WaitForChild('Mosin'):WaitForChild("Union")
local billboard = workspace:WaitForChild('BillboardPart'):WaitForChild('BillboardGui')
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Ekey = Enum.KeyCode.E
local check = false
local start = tick()


local function onpress(action1)
    if check then
        part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Black") 
    end
end


local function isKeydown(startTime)
    return uis:IsKeyDown(startTime) and startTime - tick() <= 5 
end


local function Input(input, gameprocessed)
    if isKeydown(Ekey) then
        print("h")
    else
        print("n")
    end
    start = tick()
end 

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local humRoot = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")

    uis.InputBegan:Connect(Input)
    GunStats.check3 = function()
        while wait() do
            if (humRoot.Position - part.Position).Magnitude < 5 then
                print("IN RANGE")

                check = true
                billboard.Enabled = true
                repeat wait() until (humRoot.Position - part.Position).Magnitude >= 5
            elseif (humRoot.Position - part.Position).Magnitude > 5 and check then
                check = false
                print("OUT OF")
                billboard.Enabled = false
            end
        end
    end
end)
return GunStats
```

Server Script:

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")

local serverStorage = game.ServerStorage
local gunStats = require(serverStorage:WaitForChild("ModuleScript"))
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(players)
    gunStats.check3(players)
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because the `gunStats.check3()` function isn't defined on the GunStats object until after a player joins. I would restructure your ModuleScript so that `GunStats.check3()` is defined right away :

```
--[[ define all your helper functions up here ... ]]

local GunStats = {}

function GunStats.check3(player)
    -- access the humanoid
    local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local humRoot = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")

   -- do the checks
end

return GunStats
```